# Trying to install 7zip from command line, what's next?

Tags: software-installation, 7zip

I installed Ubuntu yesterday (first time using Unix) but I can't install 7zip from command line. I've followed these steps:
http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-7zip-linux.html

Basically I have to run the sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar command and then I don't have any idea what I have to do. The tutorial just says I have to run this command but when the package was installed I run dir and I don't see any files there:

```
    claudio@claudio-Inspiron-5720:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
[sudo] password for claudio: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  p7zip-full p7zip-rar
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 964 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe p7zip-full amd64 9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2 [919 kB]
Get:2 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/multiverse p7zip-rar amd64 9.20.1~ds.1-3 [44,5 kB]
Fetched 964 kB in 6s (153 kB/s)                                                
Selecting previously unselected package p7zip-full.
(Reading database ... 208477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../p7zip-full_9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p7zip-full (9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package p7zip-rar.
Preparing to unpack .../p7zip-rar_9.20.1~ds.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p7zip-rar (9.20.1~ds.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up p7zip-full (9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2) ...
Setting up p7zip-rar (9.20.1~ds.1-3) ...
claudio@claudio-Inspiron-5720:~$ dir
Desktop    Downloads  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
Documents  Dropbox    Music     Public    Videos
```

I'll appreciate any help with this since I don't want to do it in the "easy" way using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any error messages indicating that the program was not installed.  Try starting the program `7z`

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only packages you should need to install.

It looks to have installed properly.

Now you just need to use command line or desktop interface to extract via 7zip

Answer (score 0):

To see how you can use 7zip in Ubuntu, consult the manual, type the following command in terminal to see 7Zip manual: `man 7z`.
That will tell you how to use 7Zip (press q to quit the manual).

According to that manual, `7z x archiveName.7z` will extract the file named archiveName.7z into the current directory. To extract the same file(archiveName.7z) into the current directory, we use the following: 
`7z x archiveName.7z -o path`